# Extract data from log file using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have following logfile

```
    10:12:28.571 INFO INFO McEvent (ExitWaitPostProcess) Stage: 2 
    10:12:28.571 INFO McReplay:StatusEvent: 0C0000004576656E74496E666F207631260000000A000000484C4D494E464F207631C0A80A0100007F0000010000010100000000000100000046658FDC5008000000303331333030303115000000
    5761697420666F7220706F73742070726F636573735E00000045786974205761697420666F7220706F73742070726F63657373205374616765204E6F322C20592D617869732846726F6E742053696465292C202852656172204C616E65292C205043422049443A20202020202020202020202020202020
    10:12:28.571 INFO McReplay:StatusEvent verbose: event:03130001, msg:'Wait for post process',  submsg:'Exit Wait for post process Stage No2, Y-axis(Front Side), (Rear Lane),  ID:                '
    10:12:28.571 INFO INFO McEvent (ExitWaitPostProcess) Stage: 2
```

How should my Regex look like to extract what is coming after McReplay till first line that begins with the time stamp.I have several occurrences in the file and I need all of them.

I thought about something similar to

```
               new Regex(@"^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d) INFO McReplay:(.*?)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)",
                           RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Seems I have issue with this part `(.*?)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)`

What should I fix here ?

Comment: Won't a simpler approach be to read each line of the file using System.IO methods and then doing a simple String.SubString(String.IndexOf("McReplay")) ?

Comment: @prthrokz , McReplay can be on several lines, as shown here in my small example.And I don't want to have complicated string comparison logic

Answer (score 1):

This will find all occurrences

```
     List<string> results = new List<string>();
     MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches("yourstring", "McReplay:(.+?)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
     foreach (Match item in mc)
     {
        results.Add(item.Result("$1"));
     }
```

Comment: @Blam no need for that as I don't use ^ or $ in my regex